# Recorrer un arreglo json sin conocer el contenido

Tags: javascript, json

Necesito de recorrer un array Json en donde las variables siempre están cambiando o no son los mismos y la idea es mostrarlo en una tabla o en texto simple por ejemplo

```js
{
    "variables_history": [
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T16:06:41.386Z",
            "user": "Jaime",
            "nombre": "Juan",
            "apellido": "Gomez"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T18:46:22.988Z",
            "user": "Juan",
            "fecha_nacimiento": "09/04/1990",
            "ciudad_nacimiento": "Bogota",
            "pais_nacimiento": "Colombia"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T18:50:45.988Z",
            "user": "Pedro",
            "ciudad_recidencia":"Ciudad de Mexico",
            "direccion": "Av Insurgentes 4556"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T19:30:50.988Z",
            "user": "Lina",
            "cargo": "Programador",
            "fecha_ingreso": "25/12/2019",
            "ciudad_puesto": "Ciudad de Mexico",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

La idea es recorrerlo y mostrar los datos de una forma diferente, como en una tabla dinámica o algo así 
**Ejemplos de como mostrar los datos**

```html
    Jaime escribio el dia 2020-02-03T16:06:41.386Z
    Nombre: Juan
    apellido: gomez
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Juan escribio el dia 2020-02-03T18:46:22.988Z
    fecha_nacimiento: 09/04/1990
    ciudad_nacimiento: Bogota
    pais_nacimiento: Colombia
```

Quedo muy agradecido con la ayuda

Comment: Revisa como implementar un loop como [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) o [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) para realizar lo que deseas :)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de hacerlo es así:

```js
const data =      [
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T16:06:41.386Z",
            "user": "Jaime",
            "nombre": "Juan",
            "apellido": "Gomez"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T18:46:22.988Z",
            "user": "Juan",
            "fecha_nacimiento": "09/04/1990",
            "ciudad_nacimiento": "Bogota",
            "pais_nacimiento": "Colombia"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T18:50:45.988Z",
            "user": "Pedro",
            "ciudad_recidencia":"Ciudad de Mexico",
            "direccion": "Av Insurgentes 4556"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-02-03T19:30:50.988Z",
            "user": "Lina",
            "cargo": "Programador",
            "fecha_ingreso": "25/12/2019",
            "ciudad_puesto": "Ciudad de Mexico",
            
        }
    ]
data.forEach(function(item) {
     Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
     console.log(key + ': ' +item[key])
     })
     console.log('--------------')
    })
```

Comment: Esta forma es mejor, sin necesidad de usar jquey que ya esta muriendo.

Comment: Puedes agregar una explicacion

Comment: Y, prodrías explicar ¿dónde está la partida de defunción de jQuery? o ¿cuál es su enfermedad?

Comment: JackNavaRow Muchas gracias, por la ayuda,

@quevedo Pues lo que quise decir es que hoy en día con el estándar es6 es muy fácil y amigable la programación con javascript, y lo otro es que muchas empresas (Por ejemplo Gitlab, mi persona, etc) están reemplazando jquery por vuejs ya se puede hacer lo mismo pero mas ordenado y con mucho menos código.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var json = {
  "variables_history": [{
      "date": "2020-02-03T16:06:41.386Z",
      "user": "Jaime",
      "nombre": "Juan",
      "apellido": "Gomez"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-02-03T18:46:22.988Z",
      "user": "Juan",
      "fecha_nacimiento": "09/04/1990",
      "ciudad_nacimiento": "Bogota",
      "pais_nacimiento": "Colombia"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-02-03T18:50:45.988Z",
      "user": "Pedro",
      "ciudad_recidencia": "Ciudad de Mexico",
      "direccion": "Av Insurgentes 4556"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-02-03T19:30:50.988Z",
      "user": "Lina",
      "cargo": "Programador",
      "fecha_ingreso": "25/12/2019",
      "ciudad_puesto": "Ciudad de Mexico"
    }
  ]
};

//Imaginemos que obtenemos los values contenidos en variables_history
$.each(json, function(key, variables_history) {
  console.log("Imprimiendo todos los values/objetos");
  $.each(variables_history, function(key2, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});


//Para acceder una propiedad de los objetos debes de conocerla
$.each(json, function(key, variables_history) {
  console.log("Imprimiendo una propiedad en especifico");

  $.each(variables_history, function(key2, data) {
    console.log(data.date);
  });
});

//En caso que quieras recorrer cada value de cada objecto esto valdría
$.each(json, function(key, variables_history) {
  console.log("Impirmiendo todos los valores con jquery");
  $.each(variables_history, function(key2, eventData) {
    $.each(eventData, function(key3, eventData2) {
      console.log(eventData2);
    });
  });
});


//Otra posibilidad es usar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Object.values(json).forEach(for1 => {
  console.log("Usando Objects Values")
  for1.forEach(for2 => {
    console.log(for2.date);
  });
});

json.variables_history.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log("Usando Objects Values")
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + item[key]);
  });
});

//Basicamente la idea es obtener los values/objetos en un primer ciclo, luego volver a recorrer esos values/objetos para conocer su valor
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: porque usas JQuery?

Comment: @JackNavaRow al principio estaba la etiqueta, pero igual le di las opciones usando javascript tambien. Incluso le enlaze la documentacion.

Comment: debes agregar algo de explicacion

Comment: @JackNavaRow el js esta comentado

Answer (score 0):

**Método recorrer un Array de Objetos y retornar un texto**

```
function recorerr(arraydeElementos) {
  let texto = '';
  // Recorrer sus elementos
  arraydeElementos.map(elements =>{
    // Recorrer sus indices
    Object.keys(elements).forEach(x =>{
      // Agregar su contenido a la tabla
      texto += x + ': ' +elements[x] + '\n';
    });
    // Separador de los nuevos elementos
    texto += '\n -------- \n';
  });
  return texto;
}
```

Esta es una funcion que retornara un texto con el siguiente formato:

```
"
name: Andres
ciudad_natal: Anaco
  -------- 
years: 18
name: Jose
  --------
"
```

Cuando recibe como parámetro el siguiente codigo:

```
recorerr([{'name':'Andres','ciudad_natal':'Anaco'},{'years':'18','name':'Jose'}]);
```